# How to exclude specific category id in catalog search result?

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch, category

I have to some change in magento catalog search result. I have to exclude specific category Id in catalog search result. I had tried in many way but not getting proper result. Please help me asap.

Thank you in advanced !!

Comment: Why don't you set the visibility for the products in that category to `Catalog` instead of `Catalog & Search`?

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting your suggestion. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @Marius thank you so much I am getting your point. Thank you so much.

Comment: r u talking about advance search result?

Comment: For each product there is an attribute called `Visibility` with 4 different values `Not visible`, `Catalog`, `Search`, `Catalog & Search`. This determines when will the product be visible in the website. If you set this to `Catalog` it means the products will appear in while navigating through the website, but not when your do a search

Comment: @monojitbanik No,I am talking about mini form search result.

Comment: ok.marius tells you the good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each product there is an attribute called `Visibility` with 4 different values:

1. Not visible individually - this means the products will not appear in the catalog
2. Catalog - the product will appear only when browsing the catalog
3. Search - the product will appear only in search results
4. Catalog & Search - the product will appear in search result and while browsing the catalog

In conclusion, if you set the visibility of the products in your specific category to `Catalog` they won't appear on search results.