# How to exclude or include specific category in catalog search result?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I need something like this diagram:

Navigate in Category A/B/C (Area1) -> on the left panel show a Search Module -> if the user search a term from that module i invoke Mage Catalogsearch module with a new parameter (eg: /catalogsearch/result/?q=term1&a=area1) and the result of the search have to be only from that categories.

If i search the term from the main search form (the top one) i see result from every category.

Is this possible? I've to extend/overwrite something? Any hint or suggestion?

I also see [How to exclude specific category id in catalog search result?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6633/how-to-exclude-specific-category-id-in-catalog-search-result)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in the form action the category id. So when you submit it it points to `/catalogsearch/result/?cat=13&q=term1&a=area1` (where 13 is the id of the category)

Comment: But i need the search to be done also in subcategory of the main area..